# Are these two optimization problems equivalent to each other?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_K]^T$. For a fixed vector $\mathbf{a}$, I have the following optimization problem :
\begin{array}{rl} 
\min \limits_{\mathbf{x}} & | \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} | \\
\mbox{s.t.} &  x_k\ge 0, \forall k \\ & \sum_k x_k=1
\end{array}
The second optimization problem is: 
\begin{array}{rl} 
\min \limits_{\mathbf{x}} & ( \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x})^2\\
\mbox{s.t.} &  x_k\ge 0, \forall k \\ & \sum_k x_k=1
\end{array}

My question: are these two problems equivalent to each other? if yes, how to solve them ? and which one is easier to solve ?

Comment: yes they are equivalent. have you tried the Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: The objective function of the problem 1 is $\ell^1$-norm and problem 2 is $\ell^2$-norm, so although equivalent, the objective function of the second problem is continuously differentiable, therefore the second problem is much easier to solve.

Comment: @guille_NP: The second problem is indeed much easier to solve, but definitely not for the reason you provide. Your statements about norms are simply wrong (for example, the second objective is not a norm...). Just say $t \mapsto t^2$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$  (so that the problems are equivalent) and differentiable (so that the second problem is easier).

Comment: @mat: For solving the second problem, checkout this thread which treats a slightly more general problem http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1309671/168758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which is easier? Neither. Both of these models can be solved analytically, and in the exact same way. First, let's knock out the easy cases:

1. If any $a_i=0$ for some $i$, then the optimal value of either model is clearly $0$, as demonstrated by selecting setting $x$ to be the $i$th unit vector (the vector with $1$ at position $i$ and zeros everywhere else).
2. If $a_i>0$ and $a_j<0$ for some pair $(i,j)$, then again the optimal value is zero. Just set $$x_i=-a_j/(a_i-a_j), \quad x_j = a_i/(a_i-a_j)$$ and the other elements of $x$ to zero.
3. The cases that remain are where $a$ is entirely positive or entirely negative. But if $a$ is negative, then substituting $a$ for $-a$ will not change the optimal value or the values of $x$ that achieve this value, thanks to the presence of the absolute value or square.
4. So we now have one case remaining: when $a$ is a positive vector. But in this case, $a^Tx$ is positive over the simplex, allowing us to drop the absolute value!
   \begin{array}{ll}
   \text{minimize}   & a^T x \\
   \text{subject to} & \mathbf{1}^T x = 1 \\
                     & x \geq 0
   \end{array}
   We can solve this by inspection: the optimal value is $\min_i a_i$ for the first model, and $\min_i a_i^2$ for the second. If the minimizing $a_i$ is unique, then the unique solution is the $i$th unit vector. But if there are multiple elements of $a$ with the same magnitude, any convex combination of those corresponding unit vectors is a solution.

Putting it all together, the solution is $\min_i |a_i|$ or $\min_i a_i^2$ if $a\succeq 0$ or $a\preceq 0$, and $0$ otherwise. There really was no need for case 1, but it was easy to see.

Comment: I am interested in the case where the elements of $\mathbf{a}$ are $\ge 0$. I suppose that adding a constant $b$ to the objective function, i.e. $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}+b$, will not affect the solution ($i$th unit vector) but it will modify the optimal value to $\min_i a_i +b$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Please, I have an additional question (I don't know if I have to post it in a seperate question): I want to maximize $|\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b|$, with $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}=1$, $\mathbf{x} >0$ and $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} >b$. How to solve this kind of problems. (note that $b>0$)

Comment: I think that this problem can be re-written as: maximize $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x}-b$, with     $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}=1$ and  $\mathbf{x}>0$. So the solution is similar to that in 4), with the difference of putting $\max_i a_i-b$ instead of $\min_i |a_i-b|$. Is it right ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's go for an explicit analytic construction of the set of **all** the
solutions to your problem.

**Basic notation:** $e_K := \text{ column vector of }K\text{
}1'$s. $\langle x, y \rangle$ denotes the inner product between two
vectors $x$ and $y$. For example $\langle e_K, x\rangle$ simply
amounts to summing the components of $x$.

Recall the following definitions, to be used without further explanation.

**Preimage:**  Given abstract sets $X$, $Y$, $Z \subseteq Y$.,
the *preimage* of $Z$ under $f$ is defined by $f^{-1}Z := \{x \in X |
f(x) \in Z\}$. This has nothing to do with function inversion.

**Convex hull:** Given a subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^K$, its *convex
hull* is defined by $\textit{conv }C :=$ smallest convex subset of
$\mathbb{R}^K$ containing $C$.

**Indicator function:** Given a subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^K$ its
indicator function $i_C:\mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$
is defined by $i_C(x) = 0$ if $x \in C$; otherwise $i_C(x) = +\infty$.

**Simplex:** The $K$-dimensional simplex is defined by $\Delta_K :=
\{x \in \mathbb{R}^K|x\ge 0, \langle e_K, x\rangle =
1\}$. Equivalently, $\Delta_K = \{\text{rows of the }K \times K\text{ identity matrix }I_K\}$. Each row of $I_K$ is a *vertex* of $\Delta_K$.

**Faces of a simplex:** Given a subset of indices $I \subseteq
\{1,2,...,K\}$, the *face* of $\Delta_K$ spanned by $I$, denoted
$F_K(I)$, is defined to be the convex hull of those rows of $I_k$
indexed by $I$. Trivially, $\Delta_K$ is a face of
itself. Geometrically, $F_K(I)$ is a $\#I$-dimensional simplex
whose vertices are those vertices of $\Delta_K$ which labelled by $I$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow (-\infty,+\infty]$ be an extended
  real-value function.

**Subdifferential:** $\partial f(x) := \{g \in \mathbb{R}^K| f(z) \ge
f(s) + \langle g, z - x\rangle, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^K\}$.

**Fenchel-Legengre transform:** $f^*(x) := \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^K}{\text{max
}}\langle x, z\rangle - f(z)$.

The optimal value of your objective under the given constraints can be
conveniently written as
\begin{eqnarray}
v = \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^K}{\text{min }}g(x) + f(Dx),
\end{eqnarray}
where $D := a^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times K}$, $g := i_{\Delta_K}$ and
$f:s \mapsto \frac{1}{2}s^2$. One recognizes the above problem as the
*primal* form of the saddle-point problem
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^K}{\text{min }}\underset{s \in
  \mathbb{R}}{\text{max }}\langle s, Dx\rangle + g(x) - f^*(s)
\end{eqnarray*}
Given a dual solution  $\hat{s} \in \mathbb{R}$, the entire set
of primal solutions $\hat{X}$ is given by (one can check that
sufficient conditions that warrant the strong *[Fenchel duality
Theorem](http://www.ams.org/notices/201201/rtx120100044p.pdf)*)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{X} = \partial g^*(-D^T\hat{s}) \cap D^{-1}\partial
f^*(\hat{s}).
\end{eqnarray*}
For your problem, one easily computes, $g^*(y) = \underset{x \in
  \Delta_K}{\text{max }}\langle x, y\rangle$, and so by the
Bertsekas-Danskin theorem (see [Proposition A.22](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/phdthesis.pdf) of Bertsekas' PhD thesis) for subdifferentials, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
\partial
g^*(-D^T\hat{s}) &= \partial g^*(-\hat{s}a) = ... \text{( some computations masked )} \\
&= F_K\left(\{1 \le i \le K | \hat{s}a_i\text{ is a
  minimal component of }\hat{s}a\}\right).
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
Also $\partial f^*(\hat{s}) = \{\hat{s}\}$, and so $D^{-1}\partial
f^*(\hat{s}) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^K|\langle a, x\rangle =
\hat{s}\}$. Thus the set of
all primal solutions is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{X} = F_K\left(\{1 \le i \le K | \hat{s}a_i\text{ is a
  minimal component of }\hat{s}a\}\right) \cap \{x
\in \mathbb{R}^K|\langle a, x\rangle = \hat{s}\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It remains now to find a dual solution. Define $\alpha := \underset{1
  \le i \le K}{\text{min }}a_i \le \beta := \underset{1
  \le i \le K}{\text{max }}a_i$. One computes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
  v &= \underset{x \in \Delta_K}{\text{min }}\underset{s \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{max }}s\langle a, x\rangle
 -\frac{1}{2}s^2 = \underset{s, \lambda \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{max }}\underset{x \ge 0}{\text{min }}\langle sa +
  \lambda e_K, x\rangle - \frac{1}{2}s^2 - \lambda\\
  &=\underset{s, \lambda \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{max }}-\frac{1}{2}s^2 - \lambda\text{ subject
    to }sa + \lambda e_K \ge 0\\
  &=-\underset{s, \lambda \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{min }}\frac{1}{2}s^2 + \lambda\text{ subject
    to }\lambda \ge -\underset{1 \le i \le K}{\text{min }}sa_i\\
  &= -\underset{s \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{min }}\frac{1}{2}s^2 -\underset{1 \le i \le
    K}{\text{min }}sa_i
  = -\frac{1}{2}\underset{s \in
    \mathbb{R}}{\text{min }}\begin{cases}(s - \alpha)^2 -
    \alpha^2, &\mbox{ if }s \ge 0,\\(s -
    \beta)^2 - \beta^2, &\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{s} = \begin{cases}\beta, &\mbox{ if }\beta < 0,\\0,
  &\mbox{ if }\alpha \le 0 \le \beta,\\\alpha, &\mbox{ if }\alpha >
  0.\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
 Therefore the set of **all** solutions to the original / primal problem is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{X} = \begin{cases}F_K\left(\{1 \le i \le K | a_i =
  \beta\}\right),
  &\mbox{ if }\beta < 0,\\
  \Delta_K \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^K| \langle a, x\rangle = 0\},
  &\mbox{ if } \alpha \le 0 \le \beta,\\
  F_K\left(\{1 \le i \le K | a_i = \alpha\}\right),
  &\mbox{ if }\alpha > 0,\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}

*Now that you have the hammer, find the nails...*

- **Case *(1)*: $\beta < 0$.** Choose any $k \in \{1,2,...,K\}$ such that
  $a_k = \beta$, and take $\hat{x} = k$th row of $I_K$.
- **Case *(2a)*: $a_k = 0$ for some $k$.** Take $\hat{x} = k$th row of $I_K$.
- **Case *(2b)*: $\alpha < 0 < \beta$, and $a_k \ne 0 \forall k$.**
  Choose $k_1, k_2 \in \{1,2,...,k\}$ such that $a_{k_1} < 0 < a_{k_2}$,
  and take
  $\hat{x}_k = \frac{1}{{a_{k_2} - a_{k_1}}}\begin{cases}a_{k_2},
    &\mbox{ if }k = k_1,\\-a_{k_1},&\mbox{ if
    }k = k_2,\\0, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$
- **Case *(3)*: $\alpha > 0$.** Choose any $k \in \{1,2,...,K\}$ such that
  $a_k = \alpha$, and take $\hat{x} = k$th row of $I_K$.

Comment: Dude. If I were a professor I'd want you in my research group cranking out papers. This is impressive, and you have my vote. But don't you think this is like bringing a fire truck to put out a campfire?

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Your solution is actually more elegant in many respects. Mine is indeed probably an overkill. Mindful of this, I tried to be particularly pedagocial here :) On such toy problems ($D$ is a vector, $g^*$ is a polyhedral function, etc.), it turns out that one can explicitly construct the entire solution set using Fenchel's machinery. Unfortunately, this is not always the case.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can  be equivalently modeled to LP with an extra variable, say $\epsilon$ and two more simple linear constraints, $| \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} |\leq \epsilon $. Now your problem can be rewritten as $$\begin{array}{rl} 
\min \limits_{\mathbf{x}} & \epsilon \\
\mbox{s.t.} &   \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} \leq \epsilon \\&- \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} \leq \epsilon \\  &  x_k\ge 0, \forall k \\ & \sum_k x_k=1 
\end{array}$$

Now you can solve this problem using simplex method or any other method you like!