# Steepest descent for a function defined over a specific domain

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to minimize a convex function using the steepest descent method. The function is defined over the domain $D = \{(x, y) \in R^2 : 2x^2+y^2 < 10\}$.

The gradient descent iterations:

$$\mathbf{x}_{n+1}=\mathbf{x}_n-\gamma \nabla F(\mathbf{x}_n),\ n \ge 0$$ where $\gamma$ is my constant stepsize (I tried diminishing stepsize and I get the same problem)

I easily get a solution $\mathbf{x}_{n+1} \notin D$ and then 
diverge. How should I deal with the problem of going outside the domain?

Comment: Choose $\gamma$ using Armijo's rule.

Comment: @Rajada: I am actually looking for another solution to compare to the Armijo rule.

Comment: Do you really require strict inequality in your constraint?

Comment: @littleO: the function I am trying to minimize is $f(x,y) = -log(10-2x^2 -y^2)$ so $10-2x^2 -y^2 > 0$ is an implicit constraint

Comment: In that case, I think the typical thing to do is to use a line search procedure, which will keep you in bounds.

Comment: Right. There is no need for projection for that specific function.

Comment: @littleO, we are off our game here. The optimum is obviously $(x,y)=(0,0)$. No need for a line search, gradient search, anything.

Comment: @MichaelGrant haha good point, I didn't recognize that!

Answer (score 1):

what about considering using gradient projection method, after each step, project your current result onto your constraint set.

Answer (score 0):

You are minizing the sum of a smooth function $F$, and a non-smooth function $i_D$ (the indicator function of the domain $D$) for you can compute the proximal operator, which in fact equals the projection operator onto $D$ ($D$ is an ellipsoid, so this is an easy business).

Projected gradient methods like ISTA, FISTA, etc. are your friends here.

You may want to checkout my [detailed answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311138/168758).

Comment: I was thinking this too, but the constraints have strict inequality, which I think will be a problem for projected gradient methods.  The objective function isn't finite on the boundary of the ellipsoid.

Comment: Now that the OP has offered the specific function, it is clear that no projection is necessary.