# Relation between perspective function and conjugate of linear scaling?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a convex function. The perspective of its conjugate is defined as
$$
h(y,t) = t f^\star(y / t)
$$
for $t > 0$ and $y/t \in \operatorname{dom}f^\star$.

Very similarly, if we take a fixed $a > 0$ and compute the convex conjugate of $a f$, we get
$$ (a f)^\star(y) = a f^\star( y / a ).$$

Is there any deeper reason why these two formulas are so similar?

Comment: For an introduction to the convex conjugate, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2226937)

Comment: A good reference [here](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/Archive-MIP/publis/files/07.24.pdf).

Comment: The operation $(f \lambda)(x) = \lambda f({x \over \lambda})$ for $\lambda>0$ (some details omitted) is referred to as right scalar multiplication by Rockafellar. I would recommend Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis" as an additional reference.

Comment: Really interesting question -- I have not seen something purported as a 'reason' for this. However, it's kinda cool that the theory of perspective functions illuminates that we can allow $a$ to vary while still preserving convexity! Another good ref is Bauschke & Combettes, section 24.6.