# Question about the Legendre transform

Tags: vector-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, legendre-transformation

I was reading the following

[image]

**My question**
In the first line of the proof, is the author assuming that such $\mathbf{x}$ exists such that $\mathbf{p}=\nabla f (\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{p}))$? To clarify, by definition
$$
f^{*}(\mathbf{p})=\sup _{\mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x}-f(\mathbf{x}))
$$
then I would assume that the author means to differentiate what we have in the supremum and claim that at the stationary point we must have the maximum. I would agree with this if we were told that a stationary point exists, however, this is not the case.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Legendre-Transform being finite (by definition of the domain) and convex (or rather $-f$ being concave). It must then attain its supremum.

Comment: By the way, this result holds even if $f$ is not differentiable -- it is sufficient to assume that $f$ is convex and closed (that is, lower semicontinuous). Here's how I think about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226937/40119

Comment: Hi @DrShredz, thanks for the comment. I know that the supremum has to be attained, but I am not sure that the supremum has to be a stationary point in the sense given in the first line of the proof.