# The relationship between the function and the conjugate

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

Let $f:E\longrightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ defined by

$$ f^*(y)=max_{x\in {E}}\{<y,x>-f(x)\}$$

is called the conjugate function of $f$.
where   $y\in{E^*}$ and $E,E^*$ are finite-dimensional real inner product vector spaces with inner product $<.,.>$ and norm $||.||$

Now, I want to know the relationship between the function and the conjugate function.

What is the relationship between the function diagram and the conjugate function diagram?

Comment: What are $E,E^*, <y,x>$ ?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [problem: Geometric intuition of conjugate function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874482/geometric-intuition-of-conjugate-function)?

Comment: thank you very much.